# Magento 1.9.2.4 Product Atributes are not showing on cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, cart

I am getting the product arbitrates on cart page as follows but it is not showing the values event it is not printing the product ID there:

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem()?>
<?php $_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId()) ?>
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('simpledescription')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
```

Also tried as follows still not working:

```
 <?php echo $_product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId()); ?>
 <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('simpledescription')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product).'test'; ?>
```

Comment: This should work `<?php $_product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId()); ?>`

Comment: `$this->getProductId()` ... $this is a typo here i guess. It should be `$_item `..right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all check you are editing the correct file

```
app/design/frontend/spacename/themename/template/checkout/cat/item/default.phtml
```

second check the cache is disabled.

This `$_item` object already have `$_item->getProduct()`

use **getModel**

```
<?php $_product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId()) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here is what we are searching for as cart page there is no productid has to consider

load($_item->getId‌​()); ?>

Comment: Tried Like this but still not workig:
 <?php echo $_product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId()); ?>
        <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('simpledescription')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product).'test'; ?>

Comment: Which type of product you acessing?
it is global attribute or custom attribute?
please try with $item->getProduct()->getAttributeName()
in place AttributeName  you should add your attribute name.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code:

```
<?php
        $_product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId())
        echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
    ?>
```